# I have bad ADHD and Social Anxiety, and I'm consistently annoying to other people despite it consistently yielding bad results. How do I stop?

Tags: relationships

I also have severe depression, but that doesn't really matter except for the fact that me being annoying makes me feel... not well. Yet I keep doing it, and I currently have one friend, and that one friend has just decided to cut contact with me for a month (long distance, she simply said she isn't answering my texts) because of how I always insult people impulsively, answer people's questions when they aren't asked to me, and correct people for every minor error they make. I've tried to stop my behavior, but it always comes back and although people always regard me as "the smartest person in the room" they only come to me for answers when they've exhausted everyone else in the room. I hate being treated like a personal google search, and I just want people to like me.

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your question?

Comment: Please do not delete the content of your question.

Comment: Are you currently consulting someone specialized in this type of disorders ? Medication alone can not fix the social awkwardness you struggle against, and more often than not act against you in those social cases. Have you tried looking into Cognitive Behavior Therapy ?

Comment: Wow, buddy... Sounds like you're having a rough time of it. Unfortunately, we're really not qualified to help you with most of this - as Aserre suggests, you're gonna want to talk to a specialist. But! When it comes to the more specific questions on navigating social situations, we may be of more use: just be specific and don't try to tackle too much at once. This is a long process, no need to rush it.

Comment: I'll echo sphennings and Shog9, what exactly do you need? A way to tackle a specific problem? A better way to talk? We can't give you a one-size-fits-all answer, there's a lot to do with the context and the specific nature of your problem.

Comment: Have you talked to your primare care doctor about this?  There may be more going on here, for example, have you been screened for autism, Tourette Syndrome and/or obsessive-compulsive disorder?  A simple way to get started is to print out the question you wrote here, and take it with you to your doctor's appointment.